# Python multithreaded random generation

Tags: python, numpy, random, multiprocessing

I am trying to implement in my simulation this code:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/multithreading.html

but I can't work it out.

If I follow the example in the link, I get

```
mrng = MultithreadedRNG(10000000, seed=0)
mrng.fill()
print(mrng.values[-1])
> 0.0
```

and all the other values are 0 too.

If I give a smaller input number, as 40, I get

```
mrng = MultithreadedRNG(40)
mrng.fill()
print(mrng.values[-1])
> array([1.08305179e-311, 1.08304781e-311, 1.36362118e-321,             nan,
       6.95195359e-310, ...., 7.27916164e-095, 3.81693953e+180])
```

What am I doing wrong? I just would like to implement this multiprocessing code to a random bits (0 / 1) generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in the example, I believe. You have to wrap PCG64 into Generator interface.

Try code below

```
class MultithreadedRNG(object):
    def __init__(self, n, seed=None, threads=None):
        rg = PCG64(seed)
        if threads is None:
            threads = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
        self.threads = threads

        self._random_generators = [Generator(rg)]
        last_rg = rg
        for _ in range(0, threads-1):
            new_rg = last_rg.jumped()
            self._random_generators.append(Generator(new_rg))
            last_rg = new_rg

        self.n = n
        self.executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(threads)
        self.values = np.empty(n)
        self.step = np.ceil(n / threads).astype(np.int_)

    def fill(self):
        def _fill(gen, out, first, last):
            gen.standard_normal(out=out[first:last])

        futures = {}
        for i in range(self.threads):
            args = (_fill,
                    self._random_generators[i],
                    self.values,
                    i * self.step,
                    (i + 1) * self.step)
            futures[self.executor.submit(*args)] = i
        concurrent.futures.wait(futures)

    def __del__(self):
        self.executor.shutdown(False)
```

Didn't test it much, but values looks ok